# Navigation drawer sections with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an application using ActionBarSherlock:

[image: picture 1]

I want to have sections in the navigation drawer, just like on this picture:

[image: 2nd picture]

The titles are generated from a string array. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

My java:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle)
        {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    String[] title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] subtitle = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subtitle);
    txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(subtitle[position]);

    return itemView;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ActionBarSherlock`? That is deprecated.

Comment: What should I use to have both navigation drawer and tabs?

Comment: The official Android library: AppCompat which has been around for 2 years(officially).

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, actionbarsherlock. I'd suggest getting rid of it, as it's really not relevant anymore.

What you probably need is to define two itemtypes in the adapter, one for headers and one for actual clickable items.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()

are two methods you will need to implement. In the getView() you can then distinguish which layout you need to inflate.

Also: don't inflate EVERY time. If `convertView` is not null, you can use that.

I suggest you look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

It is essential viewing for any android dev.